# Not firing ng-submit on submit

Tags: angularjs

I need to clear items ( `localstorage` ) from the cart when user checks out.

I just want to run this and then submit the form.

```
// clear the cart
shoppingCart.prototype.clearItems = function () {
    this.items = [];
    this.saveItems();
}
```

however ng-click or ng-submit dont fire, it just submits.
the form

```
<form novalidate action="http://localhost:8000/checkout" method="POST" 
ng-submit="submitCart()" class="form">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" type="submit" ng-click="submitCart()" name="Checkout"/> 
</form>
```

Couldn't find the answer i was looking for, please shed some light.

Comment: Can u share the code of submitCart() function ?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle link?

Comment: I was hoping to catch the "event" of submitting a form with angular, and then proceed to post a normal html form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `action` from the form and `ng-click` from the submit button. So the redirect to the checkout page within the `submitCart()` method

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

html

```
 <form novalidate action="#"
    ng-submit="submitCart()" class="form">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" type="submit" ng-click="submitCart()" name="Checkout"/> 
    </form>
```

js

```
 $scope.submitCart= function() {
    var data = {}

            $http.post('http://localhost:8000/checkout', JSON.stringify(data)).success(function(){/*success callback*/});
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to say that the question's title is misleading. You wont need both `ng-submit` and `ng-click` for same operation.

Use this service to send data from angularjs to wherever you want to send it to. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Your Form

```
<form method="POST" class="form">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" type="submit" ng-click="submitCart()" name="Checkout"/> 
</form>
```

Controller

```
$scope.submitCart = var function()
{
//Call the function to clear the items here.
//And now http call to backend.
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
}
```

On the contrary I'd suggest you to clear the input field after working with the callback from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to remove the action="http://localhost:8000/checkout " from the above html for the code to work and you can use a $http service in controller to post data to that url 

the correct html is :-

 <form novalidate  
ng-submit="submitCart()" class="form">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" type="submit" ng-click="submitCart()" name="Checkout"/> 
</form>

and in controller i.e app.js:-
app.controller("abc",function($scope,$http){
$scope.user={};
$http.post("http://localhost:8000/checkout",{data})
.success(function(data){ // response data back from server 

})
})

and bind the input values in form with ng-model on any object and initialise that object in controller  like <input type="text" ng-model='user.name' />

and when sending data replace data in $http.post with $scope.user and you can get the data in req.body on server side
```